# How to have a generic interface?

Tags: c#, interface

I want to have one interface for data access layer, and implement it for various databases (i.e. MongoDb, SQL Server, etc)

```
public interface IDataAccess
{
    Task InsertEntityAsync<T>(string collectionName, T entity) where T : IData;
    // the rest
}
```

and for a specific database:

```
public class MongoDbDataAccess : IDataAccess
{
    public Task InsertEntityAsync<T>(string collectionName, T entity) where T : IData
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I could make `T` to be instead of type `StudentEntity` for example, and then inside `InsertEntityAsync()` method convert it to a type accepted by that specific database.

But I want my method be generic, so if I pass `StudentEntity`, the method convert it to `StudentDocument` first then save it in db, if I pass `UniversityEntity`, the method convert it to `UniversityDocument` then save it, and you get the idea.

How to have a generic method to convert each data to a corresponding accepted type by the database?

Comment: Is the intent of your interface to be an interface for each possible database framework you might work with, or for each entity type you might work with on a given database?

Comment: @ChrisThompson Both of them

Comment: I don't really understand the downvotes. how is this too broad?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the most straightforward way to do this is to have a convert information for each type of entity, for example as a static `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` inside each type:

```
public class StudentEntity : IData  
{  
  public static Dictionary<FieldInfo, string> ConversionInfo = new Dictionary<FieldInfo, string>
  {
    {fieldinfo1, "database column name 1"},
    {fieldinfo2, "database column name 2"},
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Where you can get fieldinfo with [Type.GetField()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ek9c21e(v=vs.110).aspx).

While doing the conversion, you should iterate through this dictionary to get all the fields you need to take into consideration.

I should warn you that digging into System.Reflection (the namespace in C#/.NET that handles meta-programming-like behaviour and analyzing types at runtime) can get really ugly really fast, so try to keep it to the minimum you need to get those fields.

Please note that this is a rough, basic description of how to use this technique, you'll need to figure out the exact details based on how it fits into your actual code.