# How to have a generic method in a data access layer interface?

Tags: c#

I want to have a generic method, that converts a few known types, to their equivalent types that is accepted by the database to insert them.

```
public class MongoDataAccess : IDataAccess
{
    public Task InsertAsync<T>(string collectionName, T item)
    {
        // convert T which should be `Student`, `University` etc
        // to `StudentDocument`, 'UniversityDocument` etc
    }
}
```

How can I do this, probably using interfaces to apply restrictions?

Comment: @downvoter, would you mind clarifying the down vote?

Comment: not sure if it's possible with non-generic interface, but the class has to be generic `MongoDataAccess<T>`

Comment: I think your generic method `InsertAsync<T>` should work with generic class and interface `MongoDataAccess<T> : IDataAccess<T>`. I was looking at how `List<T>` implements `IList` and `IList<T>` https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993731/how-to-have-a-generic-interface

Comment: How is this question any different from [the one you posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993731/how-to-have-a-generic-interface). Above, you ask for a comment on a down-vote. I have a question for you: who did you cajole into **up**-voting this incredibly vague, overly broad, non-useful question? I find it hard to believe that anyone who actually cares about the quality of the Stack Overflow site would have up-voted this, especially since you already asked and apparently got an answer to what is basically the same question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho This is about a generic method, that was about a generic interface. In that one people like you were complaining that it's `too-broad` so I asked a very narrow-clear question, this one. and you still complain that it's vague and too broad, and above all, regardless of you being unhelpful and destructive to the quality of SO atmosphere, you assume I did cajole someone for an upvote!

Comment: _"This is about a generic method, that was about a generic interface"_ -- no, actually both posts have only _non_-generic interfaces, and a generic method. And you claim this is only about the method, but you specifically wrote _"probably using **interfaces**"_ And yes, this question is vague and hence too broad. That you got two wildly different answers, neither of which apparently actually address your question, is further evidence of that fact.

Comment: What you view as _"unhelpful and destructive"_ is actually quite the opposite; the criticism is constructive, intended to help you write a better question, and better questions are in the long run _constructive_ to the quality of SO.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I don't know, probably you are right. But anyway I asked a question and got the best possible answer :*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to having a "data access facade" `IDataAccess`, you can implement "entity handler" `IDataAccess<T>` per each entity type (Student, University, etc). Application code will "talk" to the DAL facade, and the DAL facade will delegate to a concrete entity handler.

The DAL facade can look like this:

```cs
public interface IDataAccess<TEntity>
{
    // no need for collectionName parameter
    // because each concrete entity handler knows its collection name
    Task InsertAsync(TEntity entity); 

    // .... other CRUD methods
}
```

An implementation of a concrete entity handler can look like this:

```cs
public class StudentDataAccess : IDataAccess<Student>
{
    // initialized elsewhere in this class
    private MongoCollection<StudentDocument> _collection;

    public Task InsertAsync(Student entity)
    {
        var document = ConvertToDocument(entity);
        return _collection.InsertOneAsync(document); 
    }

    private StudentDocument ConvertToDocument(Student entity)
    { 
        // perform the conversion here....
    }
}
```

This is how the DAL facade will delegate calls to a concrete entity handler:

```cs
public class DataAccess
{
    public async Task InsertAsync<T>(T entity)
    {
        //... obtain an instance of IDataAccess<T>
        var enityHandler = GetEntityHandler<T>();
        return entityHandler.InsertAsync(entity);
    }

    private IDataAccess<T> GetEntityHandler<T>()
    {
        // you can use a DI container library like Autofac
        // or just implement your own simpliest service locator like this:
        return (IDataAccess<T>)_handlerByEntityType[typeof(T)];
    }

    // the following simplest service locator can be replaced with a 
    // full-blown DI container like Autofac
    private readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<Type, object> _handlerByEntityType = 
        new Dictionary<Type, object> {
            { typeof(Student), new StudentDataAccess() }, 
            { typeof(University), new UniversityDataAccess() }, 
            // ... the rest of your entities
        };
}
```

Comment: Thank you dear sir, awesome! have a great day

Comment: There is one single error though. in the first line of last snippet, it shows an error: `using the generic type IDataAccess<TEntity> requires one type arguments`

Comment: I deleted `IDataAccess` interface from `DataAccess` and it works. probably that's not how it should be solved ))

Comment: @Blendester I assumed that you also declared a non-generic IDataAccess interface, but it's even better without it, so just stick to what worked -- I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use this interface.

```
IConvertible<TSource, TResult>
{
    Task<TResult> Convert(string collectionName);
}
```

Your datatypes like Student and University must implement from this.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a little bit confused. For each future class that implements my `IDataAccess` I should update `Student` for example to convert to `StudentDocument`, `StudentEntity`, etc, like `ConvertToStudentDocument()` , `ConvertToStudentEntity()`, etc?

Comment: isn't it possible the other way around? like `StudentDocument` be responsible for converting from `Student`?